# like full table in hadoop/spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

I have about 1 million records. I want manage this juridical judgments records in spark hadoop. My question is Can I query spark/hadoop for get all records at once like a full table scan? or Can I paginate efficiently for example records from 800 000 to 800 050?

My problem is that I use elasticsearch for full text search but if I want get results from 800 000 to 800 050 I'm obliged to use scroll api that appear very slow because start from 0 then take 10 000 records then others 10 000 and so on. My goal is get all records then "jump" to 800 000 without chunk of 10 000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Hive or SparkSQL can be used to query offset ranges, of datasets, yes. But they won't help with textual search out of the box.

MongoDB can do both, since it also includes Lucene indexes like Elasticsearch.